# Sort (permute) lines by length in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'm looking to sort lines by length. I see how to do it by alpha or reverse alpha, but is there a way to see shortest to longest?

Good writing mixes sentence lengths, and I'd find it very helpful if I could visualize the distribution in a paragraph or document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar question on the Sublime Text forum, you can see an answer here: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9603#p38209

There is also [a plugin](https://github.com/Doi9t/SortBy) that does this and also allows for ordering numbers in several base systems (octal, hexadecimal, binary, decimal).